# Cold Fusion 9 Redirection?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, coldfusion

I have a CF 9 installed on Windows 2008 R2 with IIS. The server has several IPs. I have created and new site in IIS and adjusted the binding on it to listen on IP other than where CF is configured. Have installed PHP and trying to browse to the simple php info file located at that site. However in the IIS logs I see that CF somehow treats it a "redirection" and shows the following in the logs: ( a simple html with "hello" loads properly)

x.x.x.x is the IP to which the site is bind.

y.y.y.y is the IP that I'm coming from.

2013-04-16 00:47:02 x.x.x.x GET /test.txt - 80 - y.y.y.y Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) 304 0 0 265
2013-04-16 00:47:08 x.x.x.x GET /main.cfm redirectionNom=info.php 80 - y.y.y.y Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) 404 0 0 156

As you can see:

GET /main.cfm redirectionNom=info.php

is perhaps causing the issue. Where should I check to try to eliminate that strange behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the ISAPI hooks that CF uses to get the requests from IIS to jrun (or tomcat in CF10) are in place for all sites within IIS, including new ones.

You can block those ISAPI filters from inheriting to this new site by putting a simple `web.config` file in its web root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <isapiFilters>
            <clear />
        </isapiFilters>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You'll then want to manually re-configure any ISAPI filters that you need enabled for this site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have created web.config file in the root of my test site. Restarted the site. Clicking on the test website showes the "home" of it with various options such as "Authentication","CGI", "Compression", etc. Among others there's a "PHP Manager" there. Clicking on it and then on "Check phpinfo()" results in error on the 4th line which marked in red:

3:     <system.webServer>
4:         <isapiFilters>
5:             <clear />

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/s3vrgfzpl/

Here's the error